# SAP Java Cloud SDK count query on SuccessFactors entity is not working

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Count query on SuccessFactors entity doesn't work as it requires $top to be greater than 0 but count() method of FluentHelperCount is overriding $top with 0. Hence the SuccessFactors rejecting the call with 400 error.

[image]

Here is my code (throws exception):

```
long count = new UserFluentHelper(QueryUtils.getSFServicePath()).top(1).select(User.USER_ID).count()
            .execute(QueryUtils.getSFDestination());
```

Executed query using Postman with URL generated by count() method

[image]

Please point me out if I am doing something wrong when constructing query.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate why your code example uses count and selectin the same query? Count returns you a number, so what is the semantics of selecting a particular entity field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, can you elaborate on the semantics of your OData query? You use `$select` and `$count` together. Referring to the [OData spec](https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#count) on `$count` it returns a plain number. I do not understand what your intention to select an entity field is based on.

Under the assumption that you only want to count entities, neglecting the additional `$select` in your shown query, here is an alternative code snippet available in the SAP Cloud SDK. Note that this API is experimental.

```java
final HttpDestination httpDestination = DestinationAccessor.getDestination("my-destination").asHttp();

final ODataRequestCount requestCount = new ODataRequestCount("/odata/v2", "User, "", ODataProtocol.V2);

final ODataRequestResultGeneric result =
            requestCount.execute(HttpClientAccessor.getHttpClient(httpDestination));

final Long count = result.as(Long.class);
```

I'll update this answer if the `FluentHelperCount` is improved.

Comment: Thanks Emdee for your answer. My intention to select only one field was to make query response lightweight. FluentHelper count construct query with $inlinecount=allpages which mean in response it will fetch all the fields of User entity and count comes as a separate field "__count" in addition to actual response.

Comment: Understood. Then, with my provided code snippet you do not need this additional projection as it uses `$count` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Update: As of Cloud SDK `3.29.1` querying the `$count` endpoint is supported.

You can change your code to use:

```java
long count = new UserFluentHelper(QueryUtils.getSFServicePath())
            .count()
            .executeRequest(QueryUtils.getSFDestination());
```

The `executeRequest` method will query the `$count` endpoint. By contrast the now deprecated `execute` method will still perform the inline count.

For details check out the [release notes](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/release-notes-sap-cloud-sdk-for-java#3291---september-24-2020).